# Typescript keeps reference and leaves two objects the same

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

copy the last position of an array, and modify the object that received the last value, but it ends up also modifying the last position, leaving the two objects the same.

```
    const visitOfTheLunch = visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1];

    visitOfTheLunch.visitPoint.name = 'almoço';

    visitOfTheLunch.lunch = true;

    visitOfTheLunch.waypoint.estimatedArrival = visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1].waypoint.estimatedDeparture;
    const backHourOfTheLunch = new Date(visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1].waypoint.estimatedDeparture);
    backHourOfTheLunch.setHours(backHourOfTheLunch.getHours() + 2);
    visitOfTheLunch.waypoint.estimatedDeparture = backHourOfTheLunch;
    console.log(visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1])
    console.log(visitOfTheLunch)
    visitMounting = [...visitMounting, visitOfTheLunch];
```

Comment: It sounds like you're putting the same object in two places in the array. Then, when you modify the value of one of that object's properties, you see that modification regardless of which spot in the array you look at, since both spots refer to the same object.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: `visitOfTheLunch` and `visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1]` are the same object. Any changes made to 1 are also changes to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I used the deep copy technique, with it we lost the references of the original object.

```
const visitOfTheLunch = deep(visitMounting[visitMounting.length - 1]);

function deep<T extends object>(source: T): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source))
}
```